# Modifying/Adding Browser Headers (Not Working)

Tags: security, firefox, ssl, http-headers, xss

(I'm still new to this and I don't know how to format this properly so it looks neat, sorry about that)

---

I'm trying to modify my **Browser Headers** but they don't seem to be changing, when checking the headers with http://ip-check.info they do show up, but when checking the headers using the **Developer Tools**, they're the same as before? I'm using **Firefox 40.0**.

---

Example (Facebook) :

- Content-Security-Policy: default-src * data: blob:;script-src *.facebook.com *.fbcdn.net *.facebook.net *.google-analytics.com *.virtualearth.net *.google.com 127.0.0.1:* *.spotilocal.com:* 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *.akamaihd.net *.atlassolutions.com blob:;style-src * 'unsafe-inline';connect-src *.facebook.com *.fbcdn.net *.facebook.net *.spotilocal.com:* *.akamaihd.net wss://*.facebook.com:* https://fb.scanandcleanlocal.com:* *.atlassolutions.com attachment.fbsbx.com;
- Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15552000; preload
- X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
- X-Frame-Options: DENY
- X-XSS-Protection: 0

---

I would like to modify the headers to this:

- X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
- Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
- X-WebKit-CSP: default-src 'self'
- X-Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'
- Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'

---

I have tried using these two Add-Ons (not at the same time) :

- https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/modify-headers
- https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/modify-header-value

[image]

[image]

Comment: Those are response headers, not request headers. How are you setting them on the server?

Comment: @Neil McGuigan, sorry I literally just realised today I was looking at the wrong headers in the Developer Tools, this addon works: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/modify-headers